# Why this code got an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I want to get next day and format it into "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" format, but when I run this in chrome's console, I got an Uncaught TypeError: date.getHours is not a function, why? The nextDay variable is clearly an instance of Date.

But when I removed hour and minute, just kept year, month and date, it successed, can anyone tell me the reason?

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
var interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var nextDay = new Date(time + interval);

function padding(number) {
    return number < 10 ? "0" + number : "" + number; 
}
function format(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        date = date.getDate(),
        hour = date.getHours(),
        minute = date.getMinutes();

    return padding(year) + "-" 
         + padding(month + 1) + "-" 
         + padding(date) + " "
         + padding(hour) + ":"
         + padding(minute);   
}
console.log(format(nextDay));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function takes a parameter named "date" and then tries to declare a local variable named "date". That declaration will be ignored, and the initializer will just overwrite the value of the parameter.

Change the name of the parameter:

```
function format(d) {
    var year = d.getFullYear(),
        month = d.getMonth(),
        date = d.getDate(),
        hour = d.getHours(),
        minute = d.getMinutes();

    return padding(year) + "-" 
         + padding(month + 1) + "-" 
         + padding(date) + " "
         + padding(hour) + ":"
         + padding(minute);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable name as the parameter, `date` is used twice, change the variable name like down below.

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
var interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var nextDay = new Date(time + interval);

function padding(number) {
    return number < 10 ? "0" + number : "" + number; 
}
function format(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        theDate = date.getDate(),   //change the variable name
        hour = date.getHours(),
        minute = date.getMinutes();

    return padding(year) + "-" 
         + padding(month + 1) + "-" 
         + padding(date) + " "
         + padding(hour) + ":"
         + padding(minute);   
}
console.log(format(nextDay));
```